# How to upload multiple image in Vue.JS and axios (Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, vuex

all day I’m trying to solve the problem with multi-upload images
In console log im see all the data but when I try to write this data to a variable im get empty array
If someone have info about solve this problem I'll be very grateful
This is my code in Vue component for upload images

```html
 <div class="card-body">
                                <form>
                                    <vue-upload-multiple-image
                                        @upload-success="uploadImageSuccess(id)"
                                        @before-remove="beforeRemove"
                                        @edit-image="editImage"
                                        :data-images="images"
                                        idUpload="myIdUpload"
                                        editUpload="myIdEdit"
                                    ></vue-upload-multiple-image>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

This is my data in Vue Component

```js
 data()
    {
        return{
            images: [],

        }
    },
```

This is my function from upload images in Vue Component

```js
 uploadImageSuccess(id, formData, index, fileList) {
            this.images = fileList;
            console.log(formData)
            console.log(index)
            console.log(fileList)
            this.addNewGallery({id, data: this.images});
        },
```

This is my code from Vuex Store from upload images

```js
async addNewGallery(ctx, {id, data})
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
            url: '/gallery/' + id,
            method: 'PUT',
            data: data,
        })
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
    })
}
```

This is my code from Console tab in browser

> [{…}, **ob**: Observer]
>   0:
>   name: "IPhoneX.png"
>   path: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC7gA"
>   highlight: 1
>   default: 1

Comment: Hey Евгений, can you please let us know what exactly is happening? The title implied that you tried to upload multiple images and that failed but the body of your question is telling me that when you try to get the result of your response it's not updating...

What would be your desired end goal for this piece of code?

Comment: _"`@upload-success="uploadImageSuccess(id)"`"_  are you sure this is correct? Your `uploadImageSuccess` method appears to require four arguments. Where does that `id` come from anyway?

Comment: I suspect this might help ~ `@upload-success="(fd, i, fl) => uploadImageSuccess(id, fd, i, fl)"`

Comment: Yes Phil im sure becose im try send request from Laravel controller Where entry parameter is ID
This ID parameter im get from props
And he, in turn, is transmitted through Vue Router
If u want im edit my task and paste such more code fragments
And i think u r undestand all

Comment: my finished code should consist of processing the request in the controller with writing data to the database and a description of the method for storing images in the controller

Comment: Thanks Phil yes its work simple mistake and i didnt see it